# How does java marshal/unmarshal complex xml objects

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have looked through various comments and documentations, however i cannot find how the JVM xml reads/writes objects, especially complex types. I am using the JAXB api bindings with annotations, more concrete using the class JAXBcontext for the marshalling and unmarshalling.
For example the doc states:

> void marshal(Object jaxbElement,
>                File output)
>         throws JAXBException -
>   Marshal the content tree rooted at jaxbElement into a file.

Which does not really uncover the process. I need a bit more information how the state of the object is processed in both directions via the parsers and the IOstreams.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the source code? Documentation will cover the *what*, not the *how*.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes i have looked through the interfaces and abstract implementations,but when i try to access the final impl i cannot from my IDE and method tracing becomes a pain in the ... when looking through plain text doc

Comment: You don't necessarily need to dig through the Oracle (Metro) implementation. You can get the sources for some other, more open implementation and look at it, unless there is some reason for you to know the inner workings of the Oracle implementation specifically.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it's my school assignment to investigate the Oracle default processes, but i am stuck and going in circles for some time now.

Comment: Your school assignment is to describe a specific implementation of the JAXB API?

Comment: @RealSkeptic it is to understand both default processes of marshalling/unmarshalling, I.e how does the xml serialization happens internally.